# Image and Video Detection with Hadoop Streaming

Tags: hadoop, video, streaming, detection

We are currently working on a project where we want execute image/video detection algorithms on a cluster of about 80-100 linux servers. We searched about possible software tools and considered Hadoop as a possible solution. I installed Hadoop on VMWare Image as master/slave configuration and was able to execute the analysis programs written in C++ via Hadoop streaming. Due to the nature of analysis algorithms we could not split the video files about 1GB in size into splits. Since Hadoop Map/Reduce works via dividing the input files into 64MB-128MB splits and assigns the programs to the corresponding node where the splits reside (data locality), I could not make the programs run on slave node but only on master node. Hence, at this point can we make Hadoop streaming execute programs based on node availability (CPU etc) but not split location on node? 
I wonder whether Hadoop is the right tool for executing image/video detection algorithms? Can there be a better solution maybe Apache Mesos/Spark etc.

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

We conducted some research on the above issue and we concluded that for our case, that is just running analysis modules for particular video files, hadoop/spark implementation will be an overkill and showing the ear from the reverse. Better implementation will be with utilizing open source MPI/Scheduler applications. After analysis even developing a job scheduler running on multiple nodes seem rather easy and could be developed in a relative 2-3 month time period

Sincerely